# Multisig Wallet Setup - Security Tradeoffs With Pruned Bitcoin Core Node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, security, multi-signature, full-node

#### What are the security tradeoffs of running a pruned Bitcoin Core node for a multisig wallet, such as Specter?

It seems that using a multisig wallet with a pruned Bitcoin Core node could be a good incremental improvement of securing assets vs. storing funds on an exchange or on a single seed hardware wallet.

1. *How is the pruned node run for Specter? Is it running off of Bitcoin Core directly?*
   I've heard that similar services, Unchained Capital, run a node supported by Blockstream if I understand correctly.
2. *Is the privacy risk mitigated by connecting Bitcoin Core's pruned node through Tor/VPN (That do not save/collect logs)?*
   Chain analysis companies are able to gather information from non-self-hosted nodes and tie it to personal information.
3. *Are there additional tradeoffs to consider?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. How is the pruned node run for Specter? Is it running off of Bitcoin Core directly?

- In the Specter setup a pruned node is directly downloaded from Bitcoin Core with the 1-click install in ≥ v1.3.0, as shown in Coinkite's *[How To Use Specter Wallet](https://youtu.be/VWze8xtH72I?t=78)* video.
- A user on bitcointalk.org provided clarity on using a pruned node in *[this post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5334772.0)*.

> Security of running a full node versus a light client is obviously higher. Being pruned doesn't change the fact that the node is still a full node, it just doesn't store the historical blocks that are too old.

- It seems I was confusing Specter's usage of Blockstream for their Bitcoin explorer with running the Bitcoin Core node which is unrelated.

#### 2. Is the privacy risk mitigated by connecting Bitcoin Core's pruned node through Tor/VPN (That do not save/collect logs)?

- The *[bitcointalk.org post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5334772.0)* also mentions there are potential privacy implications from exposing the Bitcoin Core node on a non-private IP address.

> Chain analyzers are analyzing the "chain" not the network although that is a possibility but it is a much harder thing to do. However, you do gain additional privacy when running your clients through TOR since it prevents other kinds of attack such as packet sniffing.